# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converge?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

So a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ has n$^{th}$ partial sum $s_n = \dfrac{2^n-3}{2^n}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then I just want to know 2 things: is it true that  $a_n=\frac{3}{2^n}$ and does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converges.

An Answer to the question, is $a_n = \frac{3}{2^n}$: I think because $s_n = \frac{2^n-3}{2^n}$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1$, because the partial sums limit is the sum. So $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{2^n}=0$, so it's not true.

An answer to the question, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converges: I think it's false. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1$, so $(-1)^na_n$ is not converging.

Comment: Yes according to the leibniz criteria every infinite sum with an alternating sequence b_n, which converges to 0, converges

Comment: @Maths That is false.

Comment: That is obviously not true, since $s_1=-\frac12\ne a_1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You're right i forgot to say that it has to be monotonically decreasing, but in this case it is monotonically decreasing as well

Comment: To the OP, your first argument is invalid, you've compared the limit of the partial sums to the limit of the sequence. This is comparing apples to oranges. And your second argument also doesn't hold: consider $\sum (\frac{1}{2})^n$ and $\sum (-\frac{1}{2})^n.$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that by defintion, $a_{n+1}=s_{n+1}-s_{n};$ can you now figure out what $a_n$ is?

For the second question, try using the Alternating Series test, which states that for an alternating series $\sum_n (-1)^na_n,$ if $|a_n|$ is a monotonically decreasing series, and $|a_n|\rightarrow 0,$ then the series $\sum_n (-1)^na_n$ converges.

**ANSWER**

You will get by the above hint that $a_{n+1}=\frac{3}{2^{n+1}}.$ So, you can describe $a_n$ as $a_1=-1/2$ and $a_n=\frac{3}{2^n}$ for $n\geq 2.$ So you were slightly wrong!

Now, notice that $a_n$ is a strictly monotonically decreasing sequence going to zero, and so by the alternating series test, $\sum_n (-1)^na_n<\infty.$